Google Cloud Timeseries Insights API / Precondition check failed
I'm currently trying to follow this tutorial for the google cloud timeseries API: https://cloud.google.com/timeseries-insights/docs/tutorial
I followed every step exactly like it's written there using the git bash on Windows, but this step doesn't work:
gcurl -X POST -d @query.json https://timeseriesinsights.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/datasets/dataset_tutorial:query

I get the following error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Precondition check failed.",
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
  }
}

the query.json file contains the exact content that's written there in the tutorial:
{
 "detectionTime": "2019-04-15T00:00:00Z",
  "numReturnedSlices": 5,
  "slicingParams": {
    "dimensionNames": ["EntityLOCATION"]
  },
  "timeseriesParams": {
    "forecastHistory": "1209600s",
    "granularity": "86400s"
  },
  "forecastParams": {
    "noiseThreshold": 100.0
  },
}

why is this happening?

It's possible that git bash on Windows is the issue and it's difficult for me to debug|verify this. However, you may wish to try using Google Cloud Shell (https://shell.cloud.google.com/?show=terminal) which is a browser-based Linux terminal that's much more likely to work successfully. You will need to redo the steps to alias gcurl ... but you can continue then with the Query step.
